# I want to use gdb for a c file which has header files something like this #include "config.h"?

Tags: c, gdb

I am compiling a module using make. But I am getting error in particular c file. I don't know how to use gdb in such cases.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `gdb` tool is for debugging purposes, but what you describe is a compilation problem. Posting your make file content and your error message will help the community to spot the problem and tip you any helpful advice

Comment: `gdb` works on *running* (or previously run) programs.

Answer (score 2):

gdb is not a tool to help you to resolve compiler error. Compiler errors should be resolved by reading compiler error messages and making syntax changes in your c program.